# Swagger UI is not generated in Jhipster

Tags: swagger, jhipster

I am trying to develop a little bit complex entities, the content of jdl file below. All works fine, but it is not generating the Swagger UI. Kindly advice..

Jhipster Version - 7.0.1

#### JDL File

```
application {
  config {
    baseName myApp,
    applicationType monolith,
    packageName com.myapp,
    authenticationType jwt,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    clientFramework angular
    enableSwaggerCodegen true
  }
  entities *
}

// One to One 
entity Product { name String }
entity Origin { name String}
relationship OneToOne { Product to Origin }


// Many to One 
entity Rating { name String }
entity Movie { name String }
relationship ManyToOne { Rating to Movie }



// One to Many
entity Customer { name String }
entity Address { name String  }
relationship OneToMany {  Customer to Address }


// Many to Many
entity Car { name String }
entity Owner { name String }
relationship ManyToMany { Car to Owner }
```

### Steps to reproduce

1. `jhipster jdl above_jdl.jdl`
2. `./mvnw`. --> App is running, but there is no Swagger UI for above entities.

[image: Swagger UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a JDL similar to yours, without the `enableSwaggerCodegen` line and it works fine for me.

```
application {
  config {
    baseName myApp
    applicationType monolith
    packageName com.myapp
    authenticationType jwt
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    clientFramework angular
  }
  entities *
}

// One to One 
entity Product { name String }
entity Origin { name String}
relationship OneToOne { Product to Origin }


// Many to One 
entity Rating { name String }
entity Movie { name String }
relationship ManyToOne { Rating to Movie }



// One to Many
entity Customer { name String }
entity Address { name String  }
relationship OneToMany {  Customer to Address }


// Many to Many
entity Car { name String }
entity Owner { name String }
relationship ManyToMany { Car to Owner }
```

[image: Swagger UI]

Answer (score 0):

When using the `swaggerCodegen` option there are multiple api specs. You must select `default` to see the spec for the generated entities. If you select `openapi` (as in your screenshot) you see nothing as the generated spec is empty.

[image: screenshot of generated jhipster app]